# A kind of combination problem

Tags: logic, combinations

We have 4 books of which 2 are paperbacks, and 2 are hardbacks. We have to find in how many ways we can select 3 books such that we have at least 1 paperback book `AND` at least 1 hardback book.

What I've found out so far is that

Of 3 books,

- Either (1 paperback AND 2 hardbacks)
- OR     ( 1 hardback AND 2 paperbacks )

$3C1*3C2 + 3C1*3C2$. It doesn't seem right due to its answer key which says the right answer is $4$.

> 1. Why am I wrong?
> 2. What if in the case of the fact that we have at least 1 paperback book `OR` at least 1 hardback book?

Would you mind explaining?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are in the case $1$ paperback and $2$ hardback, you are choosing $1$ from $2$ in $2C1$ no $3C1.$ If you change the $3'$s by $2's$ you will get your $4.$ (Notice that you are not choosing from the amount of chosen ones, you choose from the ones available!).
2. Does it change that much? Notice that you can not do anything else because you have just $2$ of each so you can not form something like $3$ paperback or $3$ hardback.